Flux of $ (-\sin y)\mathbf{i} + (x \cos y)\mathbf{j}$
I am trying to calculate the outward flux of the vector field $\mathbf{F} = (-\sin y)\mathbf{i} + (x \cos y)\mathbf{j}$ across the square in the first quadrant bounded by $0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0 \leq y \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.
The flux is given by:
$$
\text{Flux} = \oint \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, ds
$$
where $\mathbf{n}$ is the outward unit normal vector, or equivalently:
$$
\text{Flux} = \oint (M \, dy - N \, dx)
$$
where $\mathbf{F} = M \mathbf{i} + N \mathbf{j}$.
I attempted to compute this manually by breaking it into integrals over each side of the square, parameterizing each segment:

Bottom ($y = 0$): Flux = $-\frac{\pi^2}{8}$
Right ($x = \frac{\pi}{2}$): Flux = $-1$
Top ($y = \frac{\pi}{2}$): Flux = $0$
Left ($x = 0$): Flux = $-1$

Summing these, the total flux comes out to:
$$
\text{Flux} = -\frac{\pi^2}{8} - 2.
$$
However, when I use Green's Theorem, the flux simplifies to:
$$
\text{Flux} = -\frac{\pi^2}{8}.
$$
I believe I may have made a mistake in calculating the flux manually. Could someone help identify where I went wrong or confirm if this approach is correct?

Check "4. Left ($x=0$)"

For the line x=0, the outward normal vector is $-\hat{i}$ and limit of integration is from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to 0 ?

Yes.  But which vector $\mathbf F$ are you dotting with that $\mathbf n$ at $x=0,?$

I did like $\int_{\pi/2}^{0} (-\sin y , \hat{i} + x \cos y , \hat{j}) \cdot (-\hat{i}) , dy = \int_{\pi/2}^{0} \sin y , dy$

It sounds like you computed the flux across the square's left side, on line $x=0$, as
$$ \int_{-\pi/2}^0 \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dy $$
But the result of $-1$ doesn't make sense since along that line segment $\mathbf{F} = -(\sin y) \,\mathbf{i}$ points directly left, so the flux is definitely outward along the whole line.
Remember the flux across a curve parameterized as $(x(t), y(t))$ is
$$ \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n}\, ds = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}\, dt $$
where $s$ is the length of the curve so far, increasing from zero to the total length. So $s$ must be (weakly) increasing along the integral's range. We also know that because $\frac{ds}{dt}$ is a square root, never negative. So although $y$ and $s$ are very simply related, it doesn't work to say $y=t$ and $x=0$ and do an integral with respect to $y$ instead of with respect to $s$.
Instead, we can say $y = \frac{\pi}{2} - t$, $0 \leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then the outward flux along the left side is
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \sqrt{0^2 + (-1)^2}\, dt = \int_0^{\pi/2} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n}\, dt = \int_0^{\pi/2} +\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right) dt $$

For a vector field
$$\tag1
\mathbf{F}={M\choose N}
$$
and a closed curve $C$ the flux through the boundary of $C$
along the outward pointing normal vector is
$$\tag2
Flux=\oint_C M\,dy-N\,dx\,.
$$
So far your reasoning was correct.
That the normal is outward pointing
is most easily seen by taking a circle where
$$\tag3
\underbrace{{x(t)\choose y(t)}}_{\text{ point on curve}}\,,\quad \underbrace{{\dot x(t)\choose \dot y(t)}}_{\text{tangent}}\,,\quad
\underbrace{{\dot y(t)\choose -\dot x(t)}}_{\text{normal}}
$$
are
$$\tag4
{\cos t\choose \sin t}\,,\quad {-\sin t\choose \cos t}\,,\quad
\underbrace{{\cos t\choose \sin t}}_{\text{outward pointing normal}}\,.
$$
Taking the relationship between tangent and normal
as in (3) leads to (2).
In your Case 4 the correct way of proceeding is
$$\tag5
[0,\tfrac\pi2]\ni t\mapsto\underbrace{ {0\choose\frac\pi2-t }}_{\text{point on curve}}\,,
\quad\underbrace{{\dot x\choose\dot y}={0\choose -1}}_{\text{tangent}}\,,\quad\underbrace{\mathbf n={-1\choose 0}}_{\text{normal}}\,.
$$
The integral to evaluate is
$$
\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\sin(\frac \pi2-t)\,dt=1\,.
$$
